# Errors encountered processing mysql - Ubuntu 14.04 (Ajenti V)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am running this code to install Ajenti V on a fresh minimal install of ubuntu 14.04

```
  sudo apt-get install ajenti-v ajenti-v-mail ajenti-v-mysql ajenti-v-php-fpm ajenti-v-ftp-pureftpd ajenti-v-nginx ajenti-v-nodejs -y
```

But it is constantly bringing me with these following error codes:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
 ajenti-v-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried purging mysql* and autoclean and so

Answer (score 0):

Errors were encountered while processing:

just tells that package have problems. Is useful but not enough.
so in my suggestion you must upgrade your package or just reinstall and then again try to install all packages.